# Why is this script not copying the files inside my source directory?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I am running a script with two arguments.

```
myshell.sh source destination
```

So I want to copy all the files (not including subdirectories) inside the source directory and copy them to the destination directory.

I have the shell program and the source both in my current directory

Here is the part of the code that causing me problems 
'

```
mkdir $2
set count=0

foreach filename (* $1)
    echo $filename
    if(-d $filename) then
        echo "Not copying subdirectory $filename"
    else 
        echo "copying $filename"
        cp $filename $2
        count++
    endif
end
```

The thing is... It is copying all the files inside the current directory and not inside the source directory.

I guess the problem resides here

```
foreach filename (* $1)
```

How could I change this for it to work ?

I am using tcsh shell by the way

Comment: `count++` doesn't do what you expect it to do and is an error (you're running the command `count++`). To evaluate an expression you need to use `@ count++`. Also, don't use `tcsh` for scripting if it can at all be avoided. It had many limitations that are not easily worked around. Use a Bourne shell `/bin/sh`, `bash`, whatever) or a "real" programming language.

Comment: I haven't worked with tcsh in a long time but I suspect your problem is that the cp command is working from your PWD, not the $1 source -- maybe prefix $filename as $1/$filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only will it copy each file in your current directory, it will also tell you it is not copying the `source` directory. This line

```
foreach filename (* $1)
```

is indeed the problem, it should read:

```
foreach filename ("$1"/*)
```

(quotes are necessary in case your first directory argument contains spaces).